# Error: android.view.InflateException using nativescript plugin-feedback

Tags: nativescript, feedback

It's about this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-feedback

Someone knows why this error only on android?

IOS is working like a charm.

```
firebase.update(`/puzzle/${puzzleItem.idUser}/${currentItemKey}`, puzzleItem).then(
        (resultUpdate) => {
                this._ngZone.run(() => {
                // FEEDBACK ERROR ??!!!
                this.feedback.show({
                    message: "Easiest thing ever, right?"
                });

                this.refreshPuzzle(listIndexItemsClicked);
            });
    }
);

JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
JS: (file:///node_modules/nativescript-feedback/feedback.js:17:0)
JS:     at ZoneAwarePromise(file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:902:0)
JS:     at show(file:///node_modules/nativescript-feedback/feedback.js:15:0)
JS:     at (file:///src/app/puzzle/puzzle.component.ts:384:50)
JS:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke(file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:388:0)
JS:     at onInvoke(file:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:26256:0)
JS:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke(file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:387:0)
JS:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.Zone.run(file:...
```

Comment: Post the content of your `package.json` (see for version mismatch and possible version update needed)

Comment: Also, check when `firebase.update` can be triggered - is the native layout rendered at that point?

Comment: The update is working fine, the fields are correctly updated on firebase database. 
The error is thrown by the feedback-plugin ONLY on android. 
this.feedback.show({
      message: "Easiest thing ever, right?"
 }); 

As I mentioned on IOS the same code it works like a charm, do not throw any error... Please find below the package.json as requested

Comment: Looks like the issue iis related to the plugin being called from a promise - see this thread https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-feedback/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.help2help",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.3.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.3.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^3.0.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.20.3",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.12",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.3.3",
    "nativescript-simple-libsodium": "^1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~8.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^8.3.23",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.19.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "...",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```